# What cloud provider use for implementing simple paralell algorithm?

Tags: azure, indexing, cloud, bigdata, inverted-index

I have a task: speed up current implementation of [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index). In my opinion the best approach is to run it in the cloud:

1. Divide the input text for a few parts (or just grab a few different text files)
2. Send texts to nodes
3. Run the algorithm on each node for different input data
4. Collect the results and merge them

My question is: what is the easiest way to implement it?

My current ideas are:

- Windows Azure with worker roles - is it possible to send different data to nodes and later on merge them?
- Windows Azure and HPC Scheduler - isn't it too powerful for a task like this? I am afraid of configuration and costs (new node = new worker role?)
- Use any other cloud, like Amazon or Google - I'd like to code in c#, and I am familiar with Microsoft technologies, so I am a little afraid of them

Please give me any advices how would you achieve this goal, I am new to cloud computing (although I have some basics like mpi, soa, cuda, azure basics)

Comment: Yeah I know, the files will be larger ones, moreover they could already be on the cloud, so I hope it won't take long to distribute them to nodes.

Comment: The divide and reassemble nature of your algorithm suggests that Hadoop might be a good option. In Windows Azure's Hadoop option (which is called HDInsight) you can program your Map and Reduce functions in C# if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case for [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

In fact, [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) was created out of the needs of [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) (which does Inverted Index)

You could either use:

a) [Amazon's Elastic MapReduce](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/)

or

b) [Signup for HDInsights on Azure](https://www.hadooponazure.com/)

There are other providers ([picloud](http://www.picloud.com/) is one which comes to mind)